# Dealing with the whitespace

Tags: layers, transparency-opacity, azure-maps

I have an Azure map overlay that I'm getting from a GeoServer WMS tile source.
The layer is being added via the azure maps js toolkit, like so:

```
var geoLayerOptions = {
        tileUrl: testUrl,
        opacity:0.9,
        bounds: bounds,
        tileSize: tileSize
    };

console.log(geoLayerOptions);
currentMap.layers.add(new atlas.layer.TileLayer(geoLayerOptions), 'labels');
```

[image]

it renders like that.

I've tried to use the bounding box that covers only the region in blue, but as I scale out the bbox does, too. How can I effectively make the white areas transparent so the lower layers can be seen?

Comment: How do you consume these layers? Desktop GIS (QGIS, ArcGIS,...), web client with JS map library (OpenLayers, Leaflet, Mapbox GL JS, Maplibre, D3,...)? Can't answer without the context. Thanks

Comment: OK, will edit question, but I'm consuming it as a layer from geoserver

Comment: Try adding a dimension value in the options with transparent set to true. Something like this: `var layer = new atlas.layer.OgcMapLayer({ dimensions: { transparent: true }, url: '<service url>'})`